# Access variable of an enum nested in struct in a protocol extension in Swift

Tags: swift, swift2

I am implementing a converter that easily converts `double` type parameters of a run into proper unit according to the provided unit style, metric or imperial. Distance is entered in meters which gets converted to km or miles according to the given unit style.

`enum` for two states of unit style

```
//enum to track the states of unit style
enum UnitStyle{
    case Metric, Imperial
}
```

`protocol` implemented by every parameter of the run. This requires model to implement a type called `Unit` because every parameter has its own type of unit. e.g. For distance it can be out of km or mi whereas for speed it can be out of km/hr or mi/hr

```
//every parameter of run has to implement this protocol
protocol RunParameter{

    typealias Unit: RawRepresentable
    var value: Double{get set}
    var unit: Unit{get}
    var unitStyle: UnitStyle{get set}
}
```

This extension does all the magic. It multiplies the value of given run parameter to its suitable unit to obtain the correct value. Everything is fine till here. Now I need to get the unit description as well here in this method so that I can return it to display on the screen. For this I created a `description` variable inside the `enum Unit` but the problem is I can not access this `description` variable in protocol extension. **In a nutshell only `rawValue` variable is available on `self.unit` no `description` variable inside protocol extension.**

```
extension RunParameter where Unit.RawValue == Double{

mutating func getValueForUnitStyle(unitStyle: UnitStyle) -> Double{

    self.unitStyle = unitStyle
    return value * self.unit.rawValue
    //here I want to return both calculated value and unit string
    //but unable to access unit description on self.unit
   }
}

struct Distance: RunParameter {
   enum Unit: Double {

        case km = 0.001
        case m = 1.0
        case mi = 0.000621371

        var description: String{

        switch self{
        case .km: return "km"
        case .m: return "m"
        case .mi: return "mi"
        }
     }
 }

   var value: Double
   var unitStyle = UnitStyle.Metric
   var unit: Unit {

        get{

            switch unitStyle{
            case .Metric: return Unit.km
            case .Imperial: return Unit.mi
        }
    }
}

init(value: Double){

    self.value = value
   }
}

struct Run {
    var unitStyle = UnitStyle.Imperial
    var distance = Distance(value: 10.0)
}
```

`description` variable is available here. I can access description on `x.distance.unit`

```
var x = Run()
let z = x.distance.getValueForUnitStyle(.Imperial)
x.distance.unit.description //output "mi"
```

Comment: What error do you get when trying to access `unit.description`?

Comment: @kelin "Value of type `Self.Unit` has no member `description`" when I access in the protocol extension.

Comment: Your extension does not know about the enum `Unit`, it only knows of a typealias `Unit` conforming to `RawRepresentable`. Hence, it's natural that you cannot access properties of the specific `Enum` `Unit` located in your struct. You need to take care to differ between _"some type conforming to a protocol"_ and _"blueprinted methods and properties lined out in a protocol"_. Only the latter is available to you when extending a protocol: the protocol itself knows nothing about the _types_ that conform _to it_.

Comment: @dfri I know that but how do I make extension aware of the enum `Unit`?

Comment: Unit should conform to CustomStringConvertible protocol

Comment: @dfri Initially protocol was not aware of `rawValue` property. For that I had to add `where Unit.RawValue == Double`. How does protocol know about the rawValue in this case.

Comment: @Krishna Actually protocol extension is well aware of `rawValue` since `Unit` typealias is type constrained as `RawRepresentable`. Using `... where Unit.RawValue == Double` in the extension just tells swift that this extension is specifically for `RunParameter` conforming types where typealias `Unit` is set to `Double`. The simplest solution in this case would probably be to use a "wrapper" protocol for `RawRepresentable` and `CustomStringConvertible`, and use this wrapper protocol as type constraint for `Unit` typealias, rather than just `RawRepresentable`.

Comment: @user3441734 In that case I'll not be able to make use of `rawValue`. I want `rawValue` to be Double. Making `Unit` confirm to `CustomStringConvertible` force me to have String `rawValue`

Comment: @dfri What if I create a new protocol such that `protocol Describable: RawRepresentable{

 var description: String{get}
}` and make `Unit` to confirm to this protocol? I'm still not able to get description property.

Comment: @Krishna i modified your example, it conforms to your needs. see my answer

Comment: I hope I triggered enough research to earn upvotes from you guys so that I also become eligible to upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
enum UnitStyle{
    case Metric, Imperial
}

protocol RunParameter{

    typealias Unit: RawRepresentable, CustomStringConvertible
    var value: Double{get set}
    var unit: Unit{get}
    var unitStyle: UnitStyle{get set}
}
extension RunParameter where Unit.RawValue == Double{

    mutating func getValueForUnitStyle(unitStyle: UnitStyle) -> (Double,String){

        self.unitStyle = unitStyle
        return (value * self.unit.rawValue, self.unit.description)
        //here I want to return both calculated value and unit string
        //but unable to access unit description on self.unit
    }
}

struct Distance: RunParameter {
    enum Unit: Double, CustomStringConvertible {

        case km = 0.001
        case m = 1.0
        case mi = 0.000621371

        var description: String{

            switch self{
            case .km: return "km"
            case .m: return "m"
            case .mi: return "mi"
            }
        }
    }

    var value: Double
    var unitStyle = UnitStyle.Metric
    var unit: Unit {

        get{

            switch unitStyle{
            case .Metric: return Unit.km
            case .Imperial: return Unit.mi
            }
        }
    }

    init(value: Double){

        self.value = value
    }
}

struct Run {
    var unitStyle = UnitStyle.Imperial
    var distance = Distance(value: 10.0)
}

var x = Run()
let z = x.distance.getValueForUnitStyle(.Imperial)
x.distance.unit.description //output "mi"

print(z.0,z.1) // 0.00621371 mi
```